# How to remove words or chars from a string using coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am new to coldfusion and my goal is to remove part of a string according to certain words.

For example:

```
<cfset myVar = "One of the myths associated with the Great Wall of China is that it is the only man-made structure"/>¨
```

How can I remove the words "**One of the myths associated with the**" in order to 
have 
**Great Wall of China is that it is the only man-made structure** as string?

I used following function

```
RemoveChars(string, start, count)
```

But I need to create a function maybe with RegEx or native coldfusion functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could see the sentence as a list seperated by spaces. So if you want to cut off your sentence to start with "Great Wall of China", you could try

```
<cfloop list="#myVar#" index="word" delimiters=" ">
  <cfif word neq "Great">
     <cfset myVar = listRest(#myVar#," ")>
  <cfelse>
     <cfbreak>
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>#myVar#</cfoutput>
```

There may be a quicker way to do this. Here's a function at cfLib.org that can alter a list in a similar way: [LINK](http://cflib.org/udf/ListRight).

Answer (score 4):

I see this question already has an accepted answer, but I thought I'd add another answer :)

You can do it by finding where the word 'Great' is in the string. With modern CFML you can do it like so:

```
<cfscript>
myVar = "One of the myths associated with the Great Wall of China is that it is the only man-made structure";

// where is the word 'Great'?
a = myVar.FindNoCase("Great");

substring = myVar.removeChars(1, a-1);
writeDump(substring);
</cfscript>
```

Using mid would give you a bit more flexibility if you want to cut chars off both ends.

```
<cfscript>
myVar = "One of the myths associated with the Great Wall of China is that it is the only man-made structure";

// where is the word 'Great'?
a = myVar.FindNoCase("Great");

// get the substring
substring = myVar.mid(a, myVar.len());
writeDump(substring);
</cfscript>
```

In older versions of CF that would be written as:

```
<cfscript>
myVar = "One of the myths associated with the Great Wall of China is that it is the only man-made structure";

// where is the word 'Great'
a = FindNoCase("Great", myVar);

// get the substring
substring = mid(myVar, a, len(myVar));
writeDump(substring);
</cfscript>
```

You could also use a Regular Expression to achieve the same result, you'll have to decide which is more appropriate in your use case:

```
<cfscript>
myVar = "One of the myths associated with the Great Wall of China is that it is the only man-made structure";

// strip all chars before 'Great'
substring = myVar.reReplaceNoCase(".+(Great)", "\1");

writeDump(substring);
</cfscript>
```